# Show a field based upon checkbox

Tags: cognito-forms

Could someone tell me how to show a field based upon selections in a previous field that uses checkboxes?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

While you cannot specify this conditional logic in our Basic Editor (yet), you can just switch over to the advanced editor and enter a calculation like the following:

```
=ListOfChoices.Contains("Choice One")
```

In this case, ListOfChoices is the name of the Choice field of type Checkboxes, and "Choice One" is one of the values in the list.  You could then do other things like:

```
=ListOfChoices.Contains("Choice One") and ListOfChoices.Contains("Choice Three")
```

or

```
=ListOfChoices.Count() > 2
```

In the future when we add support for this in the Basic Editor, these calculations will automatically open in this editor, as it is just an alternative visual way of entering conditional logic calculations.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation of the syntax was what was missing for me. I could have sworn I'd done it that way but its all working now. Cheers,
Ben **Edit: Can I refer to a field that is outside the section containing the field I want to show? I seem to be able to get it to work for one section but not another. :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot currently access fields outside a section when writing a calculation inside a section. This is something we will likely address soon as it has come up a number of times recently. Our plan is to add a Form property that you can access within any calculation to "pop out" and start from the form level down to any field, as well as a Parent property that will allow you to access the parent section. Pretty technical stuff, but we are effectively enabling web form programming with just a cooler experience! Try adjusting your field layout for now to avoid this if you can.